# Can I join/group unnested objects?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am running the following to unnest some data from a large number of documents:

```
select history.*
FROM checkLog c UNNEST c.history AS history
```

Which returns:

```
[
  {
    "x": "OK",
    "created": "2018-06-19"
  },
  {
    "x": "OK",
    "created": "2018-06-20"
  },
  {
    "y": "ISSUES",
    "created": "2018-06-19"
  },
  {
    "y": "ISSUES",
    "created": "2018-06-20"
  }
]
```

This is close to what I am looking for. I would like to join all these objects on each unique date. This would be an example:

```
[
  {
    "y": "ISSUES",
    "x": "OK",
    "created": "2018-06-19"
  },
  {
    "y": "ISSUES",
    "x": "OK",
    "created": "2018-06-20"
  }
]
```

I have been able to get these results with

```
select history.created, max(x) as x, max(y) as y
FROM checkLog c UNNEST c.history AS history
GROUP BY history.created
```

**However**, in this case, the only known key-value pair is `created:date`, the other columns are transient. Because of this, I am a bit lost. I cannot `group by` with `select *` and I have been unsuccessful in joining on `created` as if it were a primary key. All the documentation I have read does not show how to do a join with unnested objects.

Thanks and apologies for my newness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this is a bit complicated, so bear with me.

Let's suppose we start with four elements in the "test" bucket, like the data you supplied. We can run this query

```
select * from test
```

and get this result

```
[
  {
    "test": {
      "created": "2018-01-01",
      "x": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "test": {
      "created": "2018-01-01",
      "y": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "test": {
      "created": "2018-02-02",
      "x": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "test": {
      "created": "2018-02-02",
      "y": 2
    }
  }
]
```

We then need to do a number of things. First, we need to group the elements with the same date. We can do this using a GROUP BY created clause and the array_agg() aggregate function, which puts all the aggregated objects into an array. That gets us this query:

```
select array_agg(test) as elements from test group by created
```

which produces this result

```
[
  {
    "elements": [
      {
        "created": "2018-01-01",
        "x": 1
      },
      {
        "created": "2018-01-01",
        "y": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "elements": [
      {
        "created": "2018-02-02",
        "x": 2
      },
      {
        "created": "2018-02-02",
        "y": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Then, with the elements of each group we then need to split each element into name-value pairs (using object_pairs()), flatten an array of arrays of objects into just an array of objects (using array_flatten()) and regroup the pairs into objects (using the OBJECT operator).

We can accordingly use this query

```
select OBJECT vv.name:vv.val FOR vv in ARRAY_FLATTEN(ARRAY object_pairs(v) FOR v IN i.elements END, 1) END as unified
FROM (select array_agg(test) as elements from test group by created) i
```

to get this output, which is what you are looking for

```
[
  {
    "unified": {
      "created": "2018-02-02",
      "x": 2,
      "y": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "unified": {
      "created": "2018-01-01",
      "x": 1,
      "y": 1
    }
  }
]
```

All of this is really rather complicated, and I encourage you to peel this query back level by level until you understand it. You can find useful documentation on N1QL functions and operators, starting here:

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/arrayfun.html

Comment: Thanks so much - clearly I have a lot to learn. I will pick this apart and use it. :)